# Implementing Set.addSequence in Swift

Tags: generics, swift

I've implemented a Set in Swift that uses Dictionary keys.  I want to implement an addAll(sequence) method that takes any sequence type over the Elements in the Set, but I'm getting an error that doesn't make sense.  Here's my code

```
struct Set<Element: Hashable> {
    var hash = [Element: Bool]()

    init(elements: [Element] = []) {
        for element in elements {
            self.hash[element] = true
        }
    }

    var array: [Element] {
        return hash.keys.array
    }

    func contains(element: Element) -> Bool {
        return hash[element] ?? false
    }

    mutating func add(element: Element) {
        hash[element] = true
    }

    mutating func add(array: [Element]) {
        for element in array {
            hash[element] = true
        }
    }

    mutating func add<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
        for element in sequence { // Error here: "Cannot convert the expression's type 'S' to type 'S'
            hash[element] = true
        }
    }

    mutating func remove(element: Element) {
        hash[element] = nil
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error in XCode 6.1 and 6.0.1.

I wanted to follow the semantics of Array's extend method, but that type signature doesn't even compile for me.

Am I doing something wrong, or should I file a Radar?

**edit**:
just found https://github.com/robrix/Set/blob/master/Set/Set.swift, which has this implementation:

```
public mutating func extend<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
    // Note that this should just be for each in sequence; this is working around a compiler crasher.
    for each in [Element](sequence) {
        insert(each)
    }
}
```

However, that just converts `sequence` into an `Array`, which kind of defeats the purpose of `SequenceType` altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update:* This has been fixed in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta 3), the original code from the question compiles without errors. (Also, defining
a custom set type is not necessary anymore because Swift 1.2 has
a native `Set` type built-in.)

---

*Old answer:* It looks like a bug to me, but perhaps someone can explain it.

Possible workarounds:

- Convert the `sequence` argument to `SequenceOf<Element>` explicitly:

  ```
  mutating func add<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
      for element in SequenceOf<Element>(sequence)  {
          hash[element] = true
      }
  }
  ```
- (As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27181111/1187415) Replace the for-loop
  by a while-loop using `next()` of the sequence generator, and type annotate
  the element explicitly with `element : Element`:

  ```
  mutating func add<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
      var gen = sequence.generate()
      while let element : Element = gen.next() {
          hash[element] = true
      }
  }
  ```
- (From ["Creating a Set Type in Swift"](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/08/creating-a-set-type-in-swift/)) Use `map`:

  ```
  mutating func add<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
      map(sequence) {
          self.hash[$0] = true
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I agree that this is a bug. Did somebody report it? Thank you

Comment: @drasto: I don't know. But in any case, if you are affected by this problem, submit your own bug report.

Comment: Using `map` seems like the best workaround.  I suppose the main problem there is that `map` really shouldn't allow side effects.

Answer (score 3):

The best I could come up with was the map solution that Martin also produced.  Interestingly enough, manually expanding the for loop as:

```
mutating func add<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
    var generator = sequence.generate()
    while let item = generator.next() {
        self.hash[item] = true
    }
}
```

Produces yet another error message at `generator.next()`:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'Self.Element??'
```

It might be somewhat more optimal to use reduce instead of map, as that doesn't build an array to discard:

```
mutating func add<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
    reduce(sequence, ()) {
        self.hash[$1] = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first variant can be made working with `while let item : Element = generator.next() { .. }`. Good idea with `reduce()`! (But both map/reduce are just hacks, a simple `for in` should just work.)

Comment: That error message is a window into the bug - `for...in` really just calls `generate()`, so the error there is likely what's blocking the `for...in` as well.

Comment: @MartinR agreed, was just throwing more info and options out there.  Definitely something the OP should be posting to bugs.apple.com