# How to make a function operate on a Sequence of Optional values?

Tags: swift

How does one specify that a function should operate on a sequence of optional values in Swift? For example, I want to make a function like this, which works for an Array of Optional values, for sequences.

```
// Given an array of optional values, return the first one with a value, if any
func firstValue<E>(ary: [E?]) -> E? {
    for e in ary {
        if let x = e {
            return x
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

What I was hoping would work, but doesn't, because because there is no such thing as `OptionalType`):

```
func firstValue<C: SequenceType where C.Generator.Element: OptionalType>(seq: C) -> C.Generator.Element {
    var g = seq.generate()
    while let e = g.next() {
        return e
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: `Optional` is itself the name of a type. (It's a generic enum.)

Comment: Your `while let` is never going to work. Suppose the sequence is the array `[nil, nil, 1]`. We hit nil, the while test fails, and that's the end of that; we return nil.

Comment: @matt: It can work because `nil` is different from `Optional(nil)`, compare https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12.

Comment: @MartinR Yup, I realized that later. Thanks for the pointer because I was also confused about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
func firstValue<E, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Optional<E> >(seq: S) -> E? {
    var g = seq.generate()
    while let e:Optional<E> = g.next() {
        if e != nil {
            return e
        }
    }
    return nil
}

let a:[Int?] = [nil,nil, 42, nil]
println(firstValue(a)) // -> 42 as Int?
```

I tested with Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2006) and Version 6.2 (6C86e)

---

**Note**

Without `:Optional<E>` in `while` condition, the compiler crashes.

And if we declare the function like this, the compiler clashes on some environment.

```
func firstValue<S: SequenceType, E where S.Generator.Element == Optional<E> > {
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ replaced E and S
```

I think these are compiler bug. Please see the comments below.

Comment: Strange. This is what I tried first, but it causes a compiler segmentation fault with my Xcode 6.1.1. Haven't tested Xcode 6.2 yet.

Comment: @MartinR Without `: Optional<E>` or `: E?` at `while`, it crashes.

Comment: @MartinR Wow, Playground and `swiftc` → OK, but with "Command Line Tool" template, it crashes. Strange..

Comment: @MartinR Could you try the updated code? just replaced `E` and `S` in the Generic parameters.

Comment: Yes that works in Xcode 6.1 and 6.1.1. So it is a compiler bug (and it took me quite a time to find the workaround :) The necessity of `:Optional<E>` also looks like a bug to me. Another workaround would be `var g = GeneratorOf<E?>(seq.generate())` which reminds me of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918594/implementing-set-addsequence-in-swift.

Comment: Thanks rintaro, this worked on Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d) (command line template) with the change in parameters. I hope Apple is aware of these bugs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two operations needed for the sequence elements:

1. Check if an element is `nil` or not, and
2. Create a `nil` value of the appropriate type as the default return value if nothing as was found.

For #2 we can use the fact that `enum Optional` conforms to the `NilLiteralConvertible`
protocol. For #1 I have defined a `NilComparable` protocol and made
`enum Optional` conform to it:

```
protocol NilComparable {
    func isNil() -> Bool
}
extension Optional : NilComparable {
    func isNil() -> Bool { return self == nil }
}
```

Now we can define a function for all sequences whose elements conform
to `NilComparable` and `NilLiteralConvertible`. All sequences of optionals
fall into this category:

```
func firstValue<C: SequenceType where
        C.Generator.Element : NilComparable,
        C.Generator.Element : NilLiteralConvertible
    >(seq: C) -> C.Generator.Element {

    var gen = seq.generate()
    while let elem = gen.next() {
        if !elem.isNil() {
            return elem
        }
    }
    return nil // Here NilLiteralConvertible is used.
}
```

Example:

```
let arr = [nil, nil, Optional(1), Optional(2)] // Type is [Optional<Int>]
println(firstValue(arr)) // Output: Optional(1)
```

---

*Update:* There is already a function

```
func !=<T>(lhs: T?, rhs: _OptionalNilComparisonType) -> Bool
```

which compares any optional value with `nil`, so the above protocol can be simplified
to

```
protocol NilComparable {
    func !=(lhs: Self, rhs: _OptionalNilComparisonType) -> Bool
}
extension Optional : NilComparable { } // Already conforming
```

Then we can write `if elem != nil { ... }` instead of `if !elem.isNil() { ... }`
in the function.

A possible disadvantage is that `_OptionalNilComparisonType` is not officially
documented.

---

*Remark:* I tried to declare the function as

```
func firstValue<C: SequenceType, E where C.Generator.Element == Optional<E> >(seq: C) -> E? {
    // ...
}
```

but that actually caused the compiler to crash. I don't know if this *should* compile.