# Swift Generic Sequence - Cannot convert the expression's type 'S' to to type 'S'

Tags: swift

I have a class that takes a bunch of items and stores them in a dictionary. The initializer takes any `SequenceType` and puts each element in it into the dictionary:

```
class MyClass<T : Hashable> {
    private var set = [T : Bool]()

    init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(_ elements: S) {
        for a in elements { // elements: Cannot convert the expression's type 'S' to to type 'S'
            set[a] = true
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile and gives the error above. The error appears at `elements` and doesn't really make any sense. I also tried `Array`'s `extends` method with `T == T` but that didn't work (as it shouldn't), but Array seems to make it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Set.addSequence in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918594/implementing-set-addsequence-in-swift)

Comment: The manual for...in loop using `generate()` worked (with a seemingly unnecessary type cast to `T`). The map/reduce ones didn't seem to like multiple-line closures for whatever reason. Thanks though!

Comment: Yes, the necessity of casting to `T` seems also to be a bug (perhaps the same underlying bug). It works also with `for a in SequenceOf<T>(elements) `.