# Tuple-type in Swift generic constraint

Tags: swift, generics, tuples

I'm trying to write a generic function in Swift with the constraint that the parameter must be a sequence of pairs (which I'm going to turn into a dictionary). Is this possible? I've tried a number of variations on the following, but the compiler doesn't like any of them.

```
func foo<K, V, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == (K,V)>(xs: S) { //...}
```

Answer (score 7):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you want to create 
a dictionary then you could define your function as an extension
method to `Dictionary` and use the fact that `Dictionary` defines

```
typealias Element = (Key, Value)
```

Then your method declaration could be

```
extension Dictionary {
    func foo<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(xs : S) {
        //...
    }
}
```

To create a dictionary from the tuples, an init method might be more appropriate, for example

```
extension Dictionary {

    init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(xs : S) {

        self.init()
        var gen = xs.generate()
        while let (key, value) : Element = gen.next() {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let d = Dictionary(xs: [("a", 1), ("b", 2)])
println(d) // [b: 2, a: 1]
```

*Note:* The enumation via `generate()` and `next()` in above code
is a workaround for the problem that, for some reason

```
for (key, value) in xs { }
```

does not compile. Compare [Implementing Set.addSequence in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918594/implementing-set-addsequence-in-swift).

---

*Update:* As of **Swift 2/Xcode 7,** the above method can be simplified
to

```
extension Dictionary {

    init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(xs : S) {
        self.init()
        xs.forEach { (key, value) in
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a compiler bug to me.

Problem here is that: you cannot use tuple type *directly* in generic parameters.

As @MartinR said in his answer, it works if we use `typealias`ed tuple type. But of course, we cannot declare generic `typealias` in global context.

For example, this compiles and works:

```
struct Foo<K,V> {
    typealias Element = (K,V)
    static func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(xs:S) {
        var gen = xs.generate()
        while let (k,v): Element = gen.next() {
            println((k,v))
        }
    }
}

Foo.foo(["test":"foo", "bar": "baz"])
```

One more idea is something like this:

```
struct SequenceOfTuple<K,V>: SequenceType {

    typealias Element = (K,V)

    let _generate:() -> GeneratorOf<Element>

    init<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(_ seq:S) {
        _generate = { GeneratorOf(seq.generate()) }
    }
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Element> {
        return _generate()
    }
}

func foo<K,V>(xs:SequenceOfTuple<K,V>) {
    for (k, v) in xs {
        println((k,v))
    }
}

foo(SequenceOfTuple(["test":"foo", "bar": "baz"]))
```

In this case, you must wrap the sequence of tuple with `SequenceOfTuple` type, then pass it to `foo()`.

Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a struct with a subscript and store the results in a Dictionary:

```
struct Matrix<K:Hashable, V> {

    var container:[K:[K:V]] = [:]

    subscript(x:K, y:K) -> V? {
        get {
            return container[x]?[y]
        }
        set (value) {
            if container[x] == nil {
                container[x] = [:]
            }
            container[x]![y] = value
        }
    }
}

var matrix = Matrix<Int, String>()
matrix[11,42] = "Hello World"

println("(11,42): \(matrix[11,42])") // Optional("Hello World")
println("(1,3): \(matrix[1,3])")     // nil
```